# Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem, - boundedness

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, monotone-functions

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral) they say the functions should be bounded. Does not the $\leq \infty$ at the end of the condition of the functions violate the boundedness? : ${\displaystyle 0\leq f_{k}(x)\leq f_{k+1}(x)\leq \infty .}$

Comment: It indeed does not say they have to be bounded. You might require some boundeness in other theorems, like Dominated Convergence type of theorems

Comment: @Tod Are you saying it does not require boundedness? See the first paragraph in the wiki link I sent.

Comment: It only assumes a monotonicity property of non-negative measurable functions.

Comment: The first paragraph does talk about boundedness but too vaguely to understand what it intends it to be applied to. Generally Wikipedia is not a good choice for these kinds of technicalities. As others have noted, bounded it not needed for monotone convergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monotone Convergence Theorem does not require the boundedness of the nonnegative increasing functions $(f_{n})$, of course, it could be $\lim_{n}\displaystyle\int f_{n}d\mu=\displaystyle\int\lim_{n}f_{n}d\mu=\infty$.

The boundedness is crucial for Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem: $|f_{n}|\leq g$, $g$ is $L^{1}$, then $\lim_{n}\displaystyle\int f_{n}d\mu=\int\lim_{n}f_{n}d\mu$.